# Role Positions: Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create roles in my server via my bot in a certain order, but every time i run the command the role positions are all wrong.

Code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "createrole")){
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Owner",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 1
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Admin",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 2
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Mod",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 3
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
})
```

[image]

In Theory this should be in order but I am not sure what is going on !

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that role create method and its data properties for position are indexed in a odd way and its indexed by 2 for a role to be higher than another.

code:

```
 if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "createrole")){
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Owner",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 5
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Admin",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 3
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Mod",
                color: "BLUE",
                position: 1
            }
        })
        .then(role => console.log(red(`Role created`)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

This is still very confusing to me but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that it gives that output, considering how roles are indexed. Please note that roles are indexed based on the `@everyone` role, for your owner role to be above your admin role it must have a higher position number. Upsettingly, I can't seem to find anything that describes this behavior, however testing does provide this behavior.

Setting Owner to 3, Admin to 2, and Mod to 1 should give your desired results.

[image: Discord role order]

... it is still *really* odd that Mod ends up above Owner with your current position values, but it is what it is I guess.

Comment: So I've tried what you suggested but it still muddled up the role position. see here: [https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/768896301256671262/769071521699332136/unknown.png](First Attempt). Which then I thought what you said about the position of owner indexed higher so i figured to set everything by 2 so mod: 1, admin: 3, owner: 5, This did give me the desired results. see here: [https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/768896301256671262/769071802274021426/unknown.png](Second Attempt) Even tho it worked, it still showed me and error. `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

Comment: `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\My Own Projects\Riven\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\My Own Projects\Riven\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/guilds/763488896892796938/roles',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 400
}`

Comment: But it would still make the roles. But after refreshing the console the error would not trigger.